# use BETWEEN between two LIKE

Tags: mysql, between, sql-like

is that possible to use MySQL BETWEEN clause between two LIKE clause?

say I want to search whose name start with A,

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name_column LIKE "A%"
```

if I want to search whose name start with J,

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name_column LIKE "F%"
```

Now if I want to search whose name start with A-J, is that possible,

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name_column BETWEEN LIKE "A%" AND LIKE "%F"
```

Please help me find some easy solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the '%' when matching a range, as it is implied in the ordering

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name_column >= 'A' AND name_column < 'K';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more thing, how can I GROUP BY this? I mean, If i want to see how many people's name start with "A" and "B" and so on...

Comment: @Shuvo, Another question deserve another Post :) this is how it goes at StackOverflow..

Answer (score 1):

In this case, a `Regular Expression` may be handy

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name_column RLIKE "^[A-J].*$";
```

Answer (score -3):

Mysql command here

$qry = select * from my_table where name_column between '%$A%' and '%$J%';

Let it not be

Comment: please remember to post in English.